# react native gifted chat failed to parse

Tags: react-native, react-native-gifted-chat

My app does not work. Any idea why I get the following error?

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/react-native-gifted-chat/lib/Actions.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
    
Failed to parse source map from 'C:\games\program\AwesomeProject\node_modules\react-native-gifted-chat\src\Actions.tsx' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\games\program\AwesomeProject\node_modules\react-native-gifted-chat\src\Actions.tsx'
Reinstall the package
```